# ArangoDB and ldap

Tags: arangodb

Two problems:

Trying to set up ldap access for my Arango instance, 3.11.7.  Using docker command line:

docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 --name my-arangodb -p 8529:8529 arangodb --log.level=DEBUG --ldap.enabled=true --ldap.server=ldap.google.com --ldap.port=389 --ldap.basedn=dc=company,dc=com --ldap.refresh-rate=300 --ldap.prefix=uid= --ldap.suffix=,dc=company,dc=com --ldap.superuser-role=project-a --ldap.tls=true --ldap.tls-cacert-file=/tmp/ldap-tls-cert.crt

I get an error that it doesn't know the option "--ldap.enabled=tru".

The end goal though is to get it working in k8s/helm.  I've put my options in the values file under dbservers.args and I can see them in my deployment ( using argocd ) but they're not listed in the pod and I can't log in either.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the so-called starter process `arangodb` the database daemon is `arangod`. Try

```
docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 --name my-arangodb -p 8529:8529 arangod \
    --log.level=DEBUG --ldap.enabled=true --ldap.server=ldap.google.com \
    --ldap.port=389 --ldap.basedn=dc=company,dc=com --ldap.refresh-rate=300 \
    --ldap.prefix=uid= --ldap.suffix=,dc=company,dc=com \
    --ldap.superuser-role=project-a --ldap.tls=true \
    --ldap.tls-cacert-file=/tmp/ldap-tls-cert.crt
```